# I tried everything possible but nothing helps for cogs

Tags: python, discord.py

what should I do if I try to connect kogi but I have them connected and what is written in them just doesn’t work ?

my code

bot.py:

```
import discord
import time
import os
import asyncio

from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents, help_command=None)

async def load_cogs():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            try:
                await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
                print(f"Cog '{filename[:-3]}' loaded successfully.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error loading cog '{filename[:-3]}': {type(e).__name__} - {e}")


async def main():
    await load_cogs()

bot.run("")

asyncio.run(main())
```

cogs main.py:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import os

from discord.ext import commands

class main(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("ready")


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(main(bot))
```

If the version of the library is the latest token I removed to post so when I run the bot everything is ok but there is no output from on_ready + when I write a simple code to respond to a command it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```py
async def main():
    await load_cogs()

bot.run("")

asyncio.run(main())
```

with

```py
async def main():
    async with bot:
        await load_cogs()
        await bot.start("TOKEN_HERE")

asyncio.run(main())
```